# Integral over orthogonal cylindrical harmonics

Tags: mathematical-physics

I am unsure how to solve an integral equation. As you know the orthogonality relation for cylindrical harmonics is:
$$
 \int_0^{2\pi}e^{in\phi'}e^{-im\phi'}d\phi'=2\pi\delta_{m,n}\
$$

The problem I have comes when you add a unit vector inside the integral:

$$
 \int_0^{2\pi}\hat{\phi'}e^{in\phi'}e^{-im\phi'}d\phi'
$$

How can this integral be solved?

Comment: Of the top of my head I'd say residues, altho Mathematica gives $\frac{-1+e^{-2 i \pi  (m-n)} (1+2 i \pi  (m-n))}{(m-n)^2}$

Comment: If you decompose the vector into its Cartesian coordinates, Cartesian unit vectors are constants and can be pulled outside the integral.

Comment: This is the solution if you don't consider $\hat{\phi'}$ as a unitary vector, else a variable $\phi'$.

Comment: David H, Is the only way to solve that? I did it and for cylindrical coordinates is not so easy. The thing is that I have to solve this: $$
 \int_0^{2\pi}e^{in\phi'}e^{-im\phi'}d\phi'=2\pi\delta_{m,n}\
$$

Comment: Sorry the time pass to edit the comments: I would like to say this: David H, Is the only way to solve that? I did it and for cylindrical coordinates is not so easy. The thing is that I have to solve this: $$
 \int \hat{\phi}Y^{m*}_nY^m_nd\Sigma=\delta_{m,n}\
$$  And this is more difficult to solve

Comment: @Tommy I don't know another way to do it, but I'd be willing to bet one exists. I have a hunch that maybe you could solve it by rewriting the integral as a line-ntegral and applying Stoke's Theorem, but I'd have to check and see if that pans out.

Comment: Ok, thank you, @David H

Comment: @Tommy Alright, I did a little bit of work and it looks like my hunch was right. If you are still interested, I'll write up a solution.

Comment: We are interested David.

Comment: Sure @David H, I would appeciate it. I am eager to know it ;)